# In terms of this grammar formula, "Although + subject + verb, subject + verb", in what situation the subject might not be a noun or noun phrase?

Tags: grammar

There is a video (https://youtu.be/UFuxlnUeGmg) talking about a tip to start a speech or an essay.

> When you give your opinion, it's a very good idea to start by saying what is good about the opposite opinion.

To illustrate, consider this example

> Although some people love eating at home, I prefer eating at a restaurant.

and then she said

> So, I have here my words: "Although", "even though". What follows is a subject. A subject can be words like: "some
>   people", can be "he", "she", "we", "the teacher". Okay? So, the subject is *pretty much* a noun.

"pretty much" means "basically" or "mostly" and indicates there might be an exception, which is not a noun or noun phrase.

In terms of this grammar formula (here is a [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238034/95044) about if this kind of thing could be called grammar formula)

```
"Although" + subject + verb, subject + verb
```

in what situation the subject might not be a noun or noun phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some classifications list pronouns separately from nouns. The subject could also be a gerund, or gerund phrase:

> Although **running** is fast, **biking** is faster.
>
> Although **eating at home** is cheaper, **eating at a restaurant** is more fun.