# Could "People", "Some people" and "Lots of people" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I used this kind of expression at another post ([Does there exist a grammar formula in grammar book?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238034/95044))

> Lots of people refer to "subject + verb + adjective" as a formula.

similarly, I could say

> People refer to "subject + verb + adjective" as a formula.

or

> Some people refer to "subject + verb + adjective" as a formula.

I guess there is no big difference among "People", "Some people" and "Lots of people" in terms of meaning, is my following understanding about this correct?

1. They could be used interchangeably both in writhing and speaking.
2. They would be used in informal cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers refer the the number of people being discussed.

"All of the people I met hate brussel sprouts." = 100%
"Most people are going to vote this year." = more than half
"Lots of people wear cotton socks." = more or less than half (less formal)
"Many of the people I know like chocolate." = more or less than half
"People are flocking to the big sale at Macy's." This suggests a lot of people without indicating a specific quantity.
"Some people are going to the new James Bond movie." = less than half
"A few people feel differently."  = a small number